# Proportional stacked area chart r and I get nothing

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to get a proportional stacked area graph like in here: https://r-graphics.org/recipe-line-graph-proportional-stacked-area

I do the following, even forcing the columne value into numeric:

this is the code:

```
mabar <- melt(ma, id.vars = c("Year"),
              measure.vars = c("ValueWW", "ValueUS"))

mabar$value <- as.numeric(as.character(mabar$value))


ggplot(mabar, aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area(position = "fill", colour = "black", size = .2, alpha = .4) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

result:

[image]

```
dput(ma)
structure(list(Year = c("1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"
), NumberWW = c(2676, 4228, 5279, 7440, 10135, 10814, 14722, 
14102, 14772, 16816, 20278, 24310, 26227, 30218, 33132, 39783, 
31047, 27201, 29573, 32953, 36025, 41407, 47455, 45173, 40710, 
44844, 43976, 41480, 39568, 43847, 48052, 49991, 53302, 50607, 
49327, 44926, 52000), ValueWW = c(347, 435, 506, 777, 758, 540, 
397, 400, 516, 624, 1039, 1217, 1824, 2678, 4116, 3623, 1866, 
1242, 1411, 2145, 2794, 4023, 4920, 3075, 2187, 2750, 2668, 2533, 
2536, 3960, 4779, 3646, 3777, 3393.563, 3370.106, 2817.39, 4898
), NumberUS = c(2309, 3447, 3708, 4443, 5840, 5982, 5702, 5915, 
6782, 8076, 9368, 11856, 13147, 14780, 13245, 14114, 9652, 8571, 
9272, 10744, 11436, 13019, 13999, 11731, 9466, 10191, 10536, 
10629, 10877, 12283, 12885, 13430, 15558, 14936, 17759, 15271, 
21000), ValueUS = c(305.64, 353.54, 373.17, 586.05, 466.09, 254.16, 
176.99, 185.13, 317.61, 414.7, 666.58, 750.39, 1116.22, 1816.41, 
2138.18, 1965.81, 1010.58, 520.54, 668.86, 1006.42, 1342.1, 1843.89, 
1967.06, 1215.09, 877.61, 981.8, 1247.04, 995.65, 1214.79, 2153.8, 
2417.39, 1784.77, 1761.54, 1931.81, 1887.57, 1125.82, 2587), 
    GDPUS = c(4579.6325, 4855.21625, 5236.438, 5641.5795, 5963.1445, 
    6158.12925, 6520.32725, 6858.5585, 7287.2365, 7639.74925, 
    8073.12175, 8577.5525, 9062.81675, 9631.17175, 10250.952, 
    10581.929, 10929.10825, 11456.4495, 12217.19575, 13039.197, 
    13815.583, 14474.227, 14769.8615, 14478.06675, 15048.97, 
    15599.73175, 16253.97, 16843.19575, 17550.68775, 18206.0235, 
    18695.10575, 19477.3365, 20533.0575, 21380.976, 21060.47425, 
    23315.08125, 23315.08125)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -37L))
```

```
dput(mabar)
structure(list(Year = c("1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", 
"1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", 
"1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", 
"2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
"2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", 
"2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("ValueWW", "ValueUS"
), class = "factor"), value = c(347, 435, 506, 777, 758, 540, 
397, 400, 516, 624, 1039, 1217, 1824, 2678, 4116, 3623, 1866, 
1242, 1411, 2145, 2794, 4023, 4920, 3075, 2187, 2750, 2668, 2533, 
2536, 3960, 4779, 3646, 3777, 3393.563, 3370.106, 2817.39, 4898, 
305.64, 353.54, 373.17, 586.05, 466.09, 254.16, 176.99, 185.13, 
317.61, 414.7, 666.58, 750.39, 1116.22, 1816.41, 2138.18, 1965.81, 
1010.58, 520.54, 668.86, 1006.42, 1342.1, 1843.89, 1967.06, 1215.09, 
877.61, 981.8, 1247.04, 995.65, 1214.79, 2153.8, 2417.39, 1784.77, 
1761.54, 1931.81, 1887.57, 1125.82, 2587)), row.names = c(NA, 
-74L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: A plot requires both data and code to produce. You have shown us your code, but without seeing your data, we can only guess at what might be wrong here. Could you perhaps edit your question to include the output of `dput(ma)`. I'm sure it will be simple to fix this if you include data-as-text that we can reproduce on our own consoles. Without it, you haven't given us enough information to answer your question. A _picture_ of your data doesn't really help us here - do you expect us to transcribe this ourselves?

Comment: thank you @AllanCameron, I tried to add that info above

Comment: Thanks for adding more info. But please NO images. Simply press `ctrl C` then edit the question, then `ctrl V`.

Comment: @AyozeAlfageme you have added a _picture_ of your data. We need the data as text, not as a picture. We cannot copy/paste a picture into our console to reproduce your data. Please paste the output of `dput(ma)` into your question so we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `Year` variable is in character format. If you change it to a numeric format, you will get your desired output:

```r
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

mabar <- melt(ma, id.vars = c("Year"),
              measure.vars = c("ValueWW", "ValueUS"))

ggplot(mabar, aes(x = as.numeric(Year), y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_area(position = "fill", colour = "black", size = .2, alpha = .4) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  labs(x = 'Year')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data used**

Please note, I had to put your `dput` through online OCR to convert the image to text, then tidy it by hand. It is much easier to select the output as text, copy it, and paste it into your question as text:

```r
ma <- structure(list(Year = c("1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", 
"1990", "1991", "1992", "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", 
"1998", "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", 
"2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", 
"2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"
), NumberWW = c(2676, 4228, 5279, 7440, 10135, 10814, 14722, 
14102, 14772, 16816, 20278, 24310, 26227, 30218, 33132, 39783, 
31047, 27201, 29573, 32953, 36025, 41407, 47455, 45173, 40710, 
44844, 43976, 41480, 39568, 43847, 48052, 49991, 53302, 50607, 
49327, 44926, 52000), ValueWW = c(347, 435, 506, 777, 758, 540, 
397, 400, 516, 624, 1039, 1217, 1824, 2678, 4116, 3623, 1866, 
1242, 1411, 2145, 2794, 4023, 4920, 3075, 2187, 2750, 2668, 2533, 
2536, 3960, 4779, 3646, 3777, 3393.563, 3370.106, 2817.39, 4898
), NumberUS = c(2309, 3447, 3708, 4443, 5840, 5982, 5702, 5915, 
6782, 8076, 9368, 11856, 13147, 14780, 13245, 14114, 9652, 8571, 
9272, 10744, 11436, 13019, 13999, 11731, 9466, 10191, 10536, 
10629, 10877, 12283, 12885, 13430, 15558, 14936, 17759, 15271, 
21000), ValueUS = c(305.64, 353.54, 373.17, 586.05, 466.09, 254.16, 
176.99, 185.13, 317.61, 414.7, 666.58, 750.39, 1116.22, 1816.41, 
2138.18, 1965.81, 1010.58, 520.54, 668.86, 1006.42, 1342.1, 1843.89, 
1967.06, 1215.09, 877.61, 981.8, 1247.04, 995.65, 1214.79, 2153.8, 
2417.39, 1784.77, 1761.54, 1931.81, 1887.57, 1125.82, 2587), 
    GDPUS = c(4579.6325, 4855.21625, 5236.438, 5641.5795, 5963.1445, 
    6158.12925, 6520.32725, 6858.5585, 7287.2365, 7639.74925, 
    8073.12175, 8577.5525, 9062.81675, 9631.17175, 10250.952, 
    10581.929, 10929.10825, 11456.4495, 12217.19575, 13039.197, 
    13815.583, 14474.227, 14769.8615, 14478.06675, 15048.97, 
    15599.73175, 16253.97, 16843.19575, 17550.68775, 18206.0235, 
    18695.10575, 19477.3365, 20533.0575, 21380.976, 21060.47425, 
    23315.08125, 23315.08125)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -37L))
```